# Error while deploying Sideload LOB apps in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, uwp-xaml

While deploying a Sideload LOB apps in Windows 10, I'm getting this error. Does anyone knows what was the issue? Please find the below links that I have followed to deploy the app
https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/windows/deploy/sideload-apps-in-windows-10

I want to deploy the app in a Windows 10 mobile. Please find the screenshot of the error

[image]

Anybody please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: I deploy the apps via DevicePortal/Browser and it works fine. try this

Comment: I want to deploy it in a mobile device

Comment: I also talk about mobile. I posted the steps that I do

Comment: have you tried the dev portal app deployment? Does it work or do you still have issues?

Answer (score 1):

On the phone, go to Settings->Update & Security->For Developers. Here activate Dev Mode and the Device portal

[image]

Now you see a IP for the connection. On your PC, open a browser and open this address http://IPADRESS/AppManager.htm

Here you see an entry `+Install app` where you can select AppX packages and deploy them:

[image]